# Visual Studio 2008 header path problem

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-7

I'm having windows 7 and visual studio 2008 on my PC. Also having two windows SDKs of v6.0 and v7.1. I'm trying to create one small application using Microsoft Media Foundation but finding one problem. All header files which i included in my project are taking from the following path

c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\

instead of taking it from

c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1\include\

Could you please tel me how to change this path??

Thanks in advance,

Sri

Comment: Fair warning: I've seen lots of users getting banned from asking questions with a profile that's similar to yours.  Read the FAQ to find out how SO works.

Answer (score 1):

Click *Start->All Programs->Microsoft Windows SDK v7.1->Tools->Visual Studio Registration->Windows SDK Configuration Tool*, select *v7.1* from the dropdown menu and click *Make Current*